# Alternatives to Bag Database

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! Are there any alternatives or similiar services as the [ROS Bag Database](https://github.com/swri-robotics/bag-database)?

Thanks!

**Edit based on community answers:**

- [Bag Database](https://github.com/swri-robotics/bag-database)
- Marv Robotics, by [Ternaris](https://ternaris.com/marv-robotics/) (also [presented at ROSCon16](http://roscon.ros.org/2016/presentations/MARVRoboticsPangercic.pdf) ([video](https://vimeo.com/187705380)))
- [BotBags: Announcing BotBags, the cloud rosbag storage service](https://discourse.ros.org/t/announcing-botbags-the-cloud-rosbag-storage-service/916)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277427/alternatives-to-bag-database/) by [tanasis](https://answers.ros.org/users/29349/tanasis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2017-12-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-12-06**:
Related question: #q218678.

**Comment by [tanasis](https://answers.ros.org/users/29349/tanasis/) on 2017-12-06**:
nice, thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Marv-Robotics](https://ternaris.com/marv-robotics/) I guess, but it requires a commercial license so there is that.

---

Originally posted by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) with karma: 700 on 2017-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1